# Total flux around a long straight conductor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, conductors

The magnetic flux density around a long straight conductor is given,
B = $\dfrac{\mu_0\cdot I}{2\pi R}$

I have integrated this expression (along a conductor of length l) in order to calculate the flux contained within distance R,
$\phi = \dfrac{\mu_0 \cdot I \cdot l}{2\pi }\left( \ln(R)- \ln(0)\right)$

However $\ln(0)$ is undefined and therefore this expression cannot be evaluated. This comes from the flux density being infinite when $R = 0$.
Have I made a mistake here?

Additionally, is it possible to use this formula to calculate the total flux (i.e. integrating from $R = 0$ to $R = \infty$ ). This formula would imply that the total flux around the conductor is infinite.

Is there an alternative way to calculate the total flux around a long straight conductor? Perhaps something along the lines of $\phi = I \cdot L$ (where I is the current in the conductor and L its inductance)

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use that tag on this type of question.

Comment: Why are you integrating with respect to $R$?

Comment: I'm integrating with respect to R as I'm trying to calculate the flux by summing the flux density along distance R

Comment: I'm trying to create a model for something I have built in the lab so I didn't use the homework-and-exercises tag @BenCrowell

Comment: What you have forgotten is that [inside the wire the magnetic field drops linearly to zero at the centre](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magin.html).

Comment: Ah indeed, thanks. That explains the $R=0$ issue, any ideas for what happens as R tends to infinity?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my poor english. My native language is french.

the divergence obtained near the wire is a general problem for wire-shaped conductors. To calculate an inductance coefficient, it is necessary to take into account the non zero area of the conductor. but then, the definition of the flux through the conductor is difficult.

In elementary courses, we mainly calculate the inductance of a solenoid which is represented by surface currents. The magnetic field is then simply discontinuous near the surface and the divergence problem disappears.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the expression for the B-field you have is only true *outside* a current carrying wire. i.e. You cannot use $R=0$ as your lower limit because that would be *inside* the wire.

If we assume that the wire has a radius $R=a$, a better model would be to assume the wire carries a uniform current density $J = I/\pi a^2$ and then use Ampere's law at a radius $R$ inside the wire, with an enclosed current of $\pi R^2 J$, to get the B-field inside the wire as:
$$\vec{B}_{\rm in} = \frac{\mu_0 I R}{2\pi a^2}\ \hat{\phi}. $$

The flux you are calculating is then the integral you have attempted with a lower limit of $R=a$, PLUS the surface integral of $B_{\rm in}$ between $R=a$ and $R=0$, which does not suffer from the infinity you have encountered.

In terms of the upper limit and the implication of infinite flux. Why would it be surprising that the flux is infinite when considering an infinite surface area? In general you should be considering the flux through finite areas.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to calculate flux $\Phi=\int BdS$ across the rectangle with dimensions $R$ and constant $l$ which is outside of the conductor. Then $\Phi=\int_{R_1}^{R_2}\frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi R}ldR$.

If this is what you've done then your result is correct.

I don't think there is any problem with infinity. If $R$ grows, the $\Phi$ should grow too, although very slowly (which can be seen by looking at the logarithm at your result.

P.S. If it's that $1/R$ in $B$ bothering you, try looking at this: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} = \infty$ Sometimes even sum of infinite series with decreasing numbers can be infinite.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but I'm still unsure how you would calculate the total flux around a conductor (this is a useful number as I can then use it to work out the proportion of flux which is coupled to another conductor)

Comment: I probably don't understand what you mean by 'total flux around a conductor'. What is the area you want to use for integration?

Comment: For conductor of length $l$, I want to know the total flux around it. Therefore the area is $l *2*\pi*R$ (surface of a cylinder) and this should be integrated for $R=0$ to $R=infinity$

Comment: Well then the total flux is zero. $\vec B$ will look like in this picture https://www.google.com/search?q=magnetic+induction+conductor&client=firefox-b-ab&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjatZKZsOrdAhVk-yoKHYp1BiMQ_AUIDigB&biw=1366&bih=694#imgrc=cH3XiELiOqnevM:   and the cylinder you are talking about is going to be parallel to $\vec B$ at every point of its surface. Normal vector of the cylinder is going to be perpendicular to $B$ everywhere and therefore $\Phi=\int \vec{B} d \vec{S} = 0$

Answer (score 0):

Line current like point charge is unphysical and leads to infinite results. For example the self-inductance of a line current loop is infinite. Two- dimensional charge or current sheets are OK in this sense.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange! Point charges are most definitely physical: consider any elementary particle such as electrons or quarks. It is then physically feasible to have such particles moving in a line which would produce a line current and this too is also physical.

Comment: Can I politely disagree? But first I should qualify my answer: they are unphysical in classical electromagnetism, because they lead to untameable infinities. Fundamental particles are described within QFT, and their point charges also lead to infinities, but tameeable ones, that is renormalizable. (Although the way I was taught it that involved cancelling infinities in a well-controlled way.Maybe there are better methods now, I am not a QFT specialist). But this question was framed within the framework of classical E&M, and I hold to my answer!

Comment: I am always happy to have a disagreement on this site because it means I normally learn something new! In this case that Stokes' theorem does not hold if there is a singularity enclosed such as the above case. This means we cannot expect Faraday's law $\epsilon=-\frac{\text{d}\phi}{\text{d}t}$ to hold true if the loop passes through the line current as this is derived from the Maxwell equation $\nabla\times\vec E=-\frac{\partial\vec B}{\partial t}$ (using Stokes') which stems from the Bianchi identity for the field strength tensor and so is a fundamental symmetry of the electromagnetic field.

Comment: So the only tools we are left with are the Lorentz force due to the fields. If you consider either point charges or line currents and tried to bring them together then the Lorentz force would increase asymptotically to preventing them ever overlapping and so there never any issues with the infinities - unless of course, the initial condition is that they already overlap but then that is just an unphysical initial condition.!

Comment: Here is a post about the Bianchi identity: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/296164/305263 and here is a post about Stokes' theorem: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2339962/945353