# Why does $\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial^{\rho}\partial^\mu A^\nu-\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial^{\rho}\partial^\nu A^\mu=0$?

Tags: tensor-calculus, maxwell-equations

The tensor $F^{\mu\nu}$ is defined as $\partial^\mu A^\nu-\partial^\nu A^\mu$. Why is the equation
$$\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial^{\rho} F^{\mu\nu} = 0$$
identically satisfied by $F^{\mu\nu}=\partial^\mu A^\nu-\partial^\nu A^\mu$?

We have
$$\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial^{\rho} (\partial^\mu A^\nu-\partial^\nu A^\mu)=\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial^{\rho}\partial^\mu A^\nu-\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial^{\rho}\partial^\nu A^\mu$$
I am told that since $\epsilon$ is antisymmetric and $\partial\partial$ is symmetric (no doubts about it), the product $(\text{antisymmetric})(\text{symmetric})=0$. Here is my attempt at understanding this last statement:

$$\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial^{\rho}\partial^\mu A^\nu=\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial^{\mu}\partial^\rho A^\nu=-\epsilon_{\rho\nu\mu\sigma}\partial^{\mu}\partial^\rho A^\nu=-\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial^{\rho}\partial^\mu A^\nu$$

1. Step 1: symmetry of $\partial^\rho\partial^\mu$
2. Step 2: antisymmetry of $\epsilon$
3. Step 3: I call $\mu$ $\rho$ and viceversa, since they are to be summed over

Then I got $\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial^{\rho}\partial^\mu A^\nu=-\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial^{\rho}\partial^\mu A^\nu=0$. Are these steps right?

Comment: The title question is a little bit obscure for me. The sourceless Maxwell equation is an applied form of the Bianchi identity. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/296164/equivalent-form-of-bianchi-identity-in-electromagnetism

Comment: A different title for this question could be "why $\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial^{\rho}\partial^\mu A^\nu-\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial^{\rho}\partial^\nu A^\mu=0$?"

Comment: Nice. Change it :)  Did the link answer your question? (and also for the queston : it is simply because of the negative sign caused by tbe index-interchange in antisymmetric tensor. So you're right)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it a little bit wrong, but the main ideas are here. Starting from $\epsilon_{\mu \nu\rho\sigma}\partial^\rho\partial^\mu A^\nu$, you commute $\partial^\rho$ with $\partial^\mu$ without changing anything. Then, you use anti symmetry of $\epsilon$ to exchange the two indices $\mu$ and $\rho$. At this point: $$\epsilon_{\mu \nu\rho\sigma}\partial^\rho\partial^\mu A^\nu=-\epsilon_{\rho \nu\mu\sigma}\partial^\mu\partial^\rho A^\nu$$
And since $\mu$ and $\rho$ are dummy indices, you can exchange them in the right hand side:$$\epsilon_{\mu \nu\rho\sigma}\partial^\rho\partial^\mu A^\nu=-\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial^\rho\partial^\mu A^\nu$$
Since that thing is equal to its opposite, it should be zero indeed.

Comment: isn't that what I did?

Comment: I had made some typos on the indices, now I think it is equal to your calculation

Comment: Yep, without the typos on the indices our two calculations match :)

Comment: perfect! thank you

Comment: You are welcome